# How to do a group by query in c++

Tags: c++, database

Hi I have a problem when executing the following query from a database to a list view in c++.

```
SELECT FN
      ,SN
      ,Team
      ,Caps
FROM PlayerProfile
WHERE Caps = (
    SELECT MAX(Caps)
    FROM PlayerProfile
)
GROUP BY Team;
```

There is no error when I execute the program without the "GROUP BY" query.
Any Help would be appreciated!

Comment: What problems do you have? What errors do you get? What happens when you execute the statement? Have you tried executing the statement in a SQL console?

Comment: What's the error? I don't know anything about your query/setup, but I'm sure that this information will help people who do. Including an error message is always a good idea with SO questions

Comment: Im using it in a c++ CLR project using windows forms. I'm trying to add all the the items to a ListView. The error I get is this "Syntax error(missing opreator) in query question"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting columns, like `FN`, `SN` and `Caps`. I suppose that if you `group by` `Team`, at least one of those columns have more than one value in at least a group.